# Setting AllowBreakAcrossPages property for row in a table

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ms-word

I am working on Windows application with c#.

I have a word document.
I am removing headers & footers in word file programatically.

I am doing this with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

after removing headers and footers, I found some tables got split in pages.

I want to set `AllowBreakAcrossPages` property to each row of every table.

How to do this in `C#` code?
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need loop all the tables in this word document. note the index start with 1, not 0 if you just want one specific table to set.

```
For each oTable As Word.Table in appWord.ActiveDocument.Tables
   oTable.AllowPageBreaks = False
   oTable.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False  'This line is very important to make it work
next
```

Check your word document to see whether your target table is embedded in some other, make sure the loop access the target table for the property setting.

Comment: please format your answer correctly. text is not code